# TouchMajor and TouchMinor in C# UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

Is it possible to get Android Like Touch Major and Touch Minor in C# UWP.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.PointerCoords#touchMajor
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.PointerCoords#touchMinor

Purpose:
Need to detect touch shape in c# UWP

Comment: Currently, there is no similar method like Touch Major and Touch Minor in uwp. What does 'Need to detect touch shape' mean? Can you show more details about your expected behavior?

Comment: I need to calculate approx Ellipse Area / Touched Area made by touch...

Comment: There is no directly way can calculate the touched area in uwp. But you can subscribe the [Manipulation events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/touch-interactions#manipulation-events) to get each point you touch. Then based on these points, you can draw a [Polygon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/shapes#polygon) shape. After that, you can get the DesiredSize.Width and DesiredSize.Height which represent the maximum width and height of Polygon to calculate the area.

Comment: sorry may I couldn't clarify the issue,
I need touch shape of of a "Single Touch" event. (i.e Shape of touch on Tap event ). 
Not drawn shape after dragging or moving touch.

Comment: If you want to get the touch shape on Tap event, currently there is no api can achieve it in uwp.